# Ajax show Dynamic data of php in html drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to get the data from a database and populate then  in a drop down in the code below.

I am unable to populate them as the data output says:
"undefined index: selectid" from php ma be the data is not passing from ajax or the php is unable to read.

HTML:

```
<select id="dynamicDropdown"></select>
```

JS:

```
var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("id");
    $.ajax({
        url : "DD.php",
        data: {"storedValue":storedValue},


        success : function(data){

            alert(data);
            console.log(data)  // data should be an array that you have mentioned.
            data.map(function(c){
                $("#dynamicDropdown").append("<option value="+c.C_CO+">"+c.C_NAME1+"</option>");
            });
        }
    });
    };
```

PHP:

```
$mysqli=mysqli_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx');

$selectid =  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,trim($_POST['storedValue']));


$query112 ="SELECT * FROM dd_table  WHERE  id='$selectid'";
$result112 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query112)or die(mysqli_error());
$num_row112 = mysqli_num_rows($result112);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result112))
{


$response = array($row['dd_data'] );

echo json_encode($response); 
}
```

Comment: you should create option list in php then add returned data to dropdown

Comment: @SimiTKD thnx for reply can u help me on that??

Comment: set contentType to text/plain in your ajax function and add returned value to dropdown for detail you can search about content type of ajax() function

Comment: @SimiTKD it dint work

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but shouldn't you write it like this : 
$query112 ="SELECT * FROM dd_table  WHERE  id='".$selectid."'"; ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any jQuery for that:

Try this:

```
<select>
    <?php 
        foreach(mysqli_fetch_array($result112) as $x){
           echo "<option>". $x['dd_data']. "</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: i can use this but have a problem as this dive is to b displayed in multiple div and i cannot implement this there.

Comment: Then just add it to the other `div`?

Comment: my problem is i have a list view whey are populated from data base as u have suggested me to do and if i click on then that particulate list selected list take to a specified div where that div is populated from another php which contains two date pickers but this drop down also should b shown in each of the div But this drop down data is in a another table when am merging two div then nothing shows up so what i thought was php populates the`< select >`tag  and the js fill the `<option>` on that.